# Is this CSS code correct?

Tags: css

```
.divTest { 
    min-height: 500px; 
    height: auto !important; 
    height: 500px; 
}
```

I have got this following CSS code, I tested it on http://www.cleancss.com/ and it took out the `height: 500px`. Any reasons why that happened?

Comment: this is design to work with IE6 inability to set min-height, hack is explained here http://www.dustindiaz.com/min-height-fast-hack/

Comment: is it possible for me to get some feedback from anywhere for the CSS code i have written for a website i developed? Its just that i got some feedback saying its not strong enough and not accessible

Comment: Do you seriously still care about layout quirks in IE6?

Comment: @eamon i dont but unfortunately my clients do

Comment: @eamon A desktop user can opt to upgrade, but many corporations lock down the upgrade cycle and fixated on IE6 (i.e. they see no reason to upgrade and they developed intranet tools that only work/display in IE6).  Lets hope they learn from this one and develop cross-browser standards compliant sites the next time around :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`!important` commands take over any other... so your `height:500px;` line will always be ignored (which is why the optimizer took the line out).

If you want your div to have a height of 500px only then your CSS should just be:

```
.divTest {
    height:500px;
}
```

If you want your div to have a varying height, no smaller than 500px then your CSS should be:

```
.divTest {
    min-height: 500px;
    /* height:auto; - implied */
}
```

You don't need the `!important` for this css-fragment, unless there's some other rule that's effecting the height and you need to override it.  You don't need to specify `height:auto` because that's the default style for a div (unless of course you're inheriting something else ;))

If you're using IE6 there's a [work around](http://davidwalsh.name/cross-browser-css-min-height):

```
.divTest {min-height:500px;}
* html .divTest {height:500px;}
```

Comment: @Rudu It's an optimizer, not validator.

Comment: @rudu will it mean my code is not strong enough? the reason im asking is because i was told the css code i have written for a website is not strong enough and accessible

Comment: @Rudu In the second scenario, why not just `.divTest { min-height: 500px }`?

Comment: @rudu i did exactly like you suggested and it doesn not work properly in IE6,hence i had to put height:500px;

Comment: @maraj82: what does "not strong enough" mean?  I've never heard that before

Comment: @Šime - is it another one of your sites?

Comment: @Rudu What site? cleancss.com? That's not mine.

Comment: @chris lively i wish i knew what he meant by "not strong enough", he also said it was not clean and accessible,i thought i had coded it well but after that feedback im a bit worried

Comment: @manraj82: Talk to whoever gave you this analysis and ask them for explicit examples on what to do.  This will be the best way for you to learn AND understand what this person is looking for

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why it did that but setting height to 500px won't do anything if you declare height: auto to be important.